# Git, so when should we use rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

Only when there 'll be no further commit to the branch?

Which implies:
Share branch (published branch) is not a good fit for `rebase`.

Are there other restrictions on when to use `rebase`?

Comment: it does not matter if there will be any new commits to the branch or not. the reason that you use rebase , is to keep the commits made to the branch on top of whatever new changes you pull into the branch.

Answer (score 1):

the only problem with using rebase, is that it changes the history.
so as long as you are not on the master branch, where it is advisable to retain history, you can use rebase all the time.
maybe use git rebase --committer-date-is-author-date to keep the committers date

If you've already screwed up the commit dates  and want to reset them to their corresponding author dates, you can run:

git filter-branch --env-filter 'GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE; export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE'